# How to end one procedure (Sub, Function etc) from another in VBA?

Tags: vba

I want to end a main sub from another sub or function.

Here is an example code to illustrate what I need to do:

```
Sub main()

    Call endMainSub

    'do other stuff

End Sub

Sub endMainSub()

    'here I need a code to break main Sub

End Sub
```

From `endMainSub`, I would like to terminate `main` sub before `"do other stuff"`.

Comment: Just handover a parameter to the sub - keep in mind to explicitly set it ByRef

Comment: Exit Sub? ends the Sub.

Comment: You can not end function from inside of another function. First you need to return execution to the main function before end it.

Comment: Please remove one of the `vba` or `vb.net` tags. This is are totally different technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`End` Finishes all code execution. Alternatively, if you need more control, have a global flag (a boolean variable), based on which execution will continue or not.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a function for that.

```
Sub main()

    If Not endMainSub Then
        'do other stuff
    End If
End Sub

Private Function endMainSub() As Boolean

    Dim Fun As Boolean          ' function return value
    
    ' break if A3 = "No" OR C3 > 10
    Fun = (Cells(3, "A").Value = "No")
    If Not Fun Then
        Fun = (Cells(3, "C").Value > 10)
    End If

    endMainSub = Fun
End Function
```

Make the function `Private` if you aren't going to call it from another module. Remove the `Private` to make it `Public` by default.

Comment: Rather than assigning a value to the Function name, the Return keyword it more common now in vb.net.

Comment: @Mary Absolutely. My suggestion is using VBA syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize. I not sure I ever worked with VBA. The question should not be tagged with both VBA and vb.net. 2 entirely different languages.

Comment: @Mary This should *possibly* be VB6/VBA since the syntax is basically the same.