# How to end one procedure (Sub, Function) from another in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to end a main sub from another sub.

Here is an example code to illustrate what I need to do:

```
Sub main()

    endMainSub()

    'do other stuff

End Sub

Sub endMainSub()

    **'here I need a code to end main Sub**

End Sub
```

From endMainSub, I would like to terminate main sub before "do other stuff".
I need something like "End" in VBA.

Comment: Why are you [re-posting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63083332/11159372) a question you already accepted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63083360/11159372) to?

Comment: The other question was for VBA and this is for VB .net

Comment: You can not! You need return execution from one method to another before another function can be exited.

Comment: The most general solution is to `Throw` an exception.  This will end everything in the call stack up until the point where there is a matching `Catch` (or bring down the program if there isn't a matching `Catch`).

Answer (score 1):

`End` exists in VB.NET too, so you could use it. You should NEVER do so though. `End` simply stops executing the application at that point, with no regard for what state it might be in. It's like closing applications by using *End Task* in *Task Manager*, which I hope you use only as a last resort.

As suggested, you should be returning a result from the second method that indicates that the application should exit and the first method should explicitly choose to exit or not based on that, e.g.

```vb
Sub Main()
    If EndMainSub() Then
        Return
    End If

    '...
End Sub

Function EndMainSub() As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean

    'Some work that sets result here.

    Return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
Application.Exit
```

It's more object orientated and allows to execute all closing and disposing events. "End" still exists, but it will end immediately and no clean up routines will be executed.

Comment: This answer is true only if you want exit from an application. But not from another function.

Comment: Based on the code, this is for a console application. `Application.Exit` applies to WinForms and WPF apps.